# How do I add empty (white) space between lines in my PlantUML Sequence Diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, plantuml

I'm creating some notes and images to help me better understand Builder Patterns in Java.

Strictly for design purposes, I've been attempting to input additional white space between some message lines I have in a PlantUML Sequence Diagram.

More specifically ... I want additional white space between the `LibraryController -> Book.Builder : init` line and `LibraryController -> Book.Builder : isbn(String isbn)`.

[image: 1]

[image]

I've tried using `\n` at the end of the `init` statement, but that only added extra white space between the `init` text and its line.

I'm looking to add extra space between the `init` line and the following text + `isbn(String isbn)` line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Instead copy the code as text in your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [sequence diagram syntax has this feature](https://plantuml.com/sequence-diagram#d511f8439ecde366) with vertical bars:

```
@startuml

Alice -> Bob: message 1
Bob --> Alice: ok
|||
Alice -> Bob: message 2
Bob --> Alice: ok
||45||
Alice -> Bob: message 3
Bob --> Alice: ok

@enduml
```

[image]

Another way is to add the `\n` before the message, e.g.,

```
@startuml
Alice --> Bob: whazzup?
Bob --> Alice: \n\n\n\n\n\nyo
@enduml
```

[image]